# Make an Absolute positioned carousel responsive

Tags: html, css

I have a carousel on a web page that I have absolute positioning on of top:420px and left:640px. I would like for it to collapse and become vertical when the screen size changes. I put the media query in display:flex flex-direction: column. The slider doesn't move from its absolute position. Is there a way I can make it responsive and collapse to a column when screen size is smaller.

```
.main { 
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-width: 50%;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 420px;
    left: 640px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .main {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
}

.main div img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: can you post your html and all relevant css in snippet

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

`display:flex` and  `flex-direction: column` only affects the inner arrangement of your div. In order to change your div's position, you'll have to change the `top` and `left` values. For example:

```css
.main { 
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-width: 50%;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 420px;
    left: 640px;
    display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .main {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
    }
}

.main div img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>First div</div>
  <div>Second div</div>
</div>
```